# Worker threads send many messages through a channel to main but only the first one is delivered

Tags: rust

I've been trying to extend the thread pool example from the Multi-Threaded Web Server chapter in The Book. The original example works fine and dispatches messages to workers properly though the spsc channel (ingress), but now I want to return values (strings) from the worker threads through an mpsc channel (egress). Somehow the egress channel sends only one message instead of 10. egress_tx.send() seems to be executed 10 times but egress_rx.recv() gives me one message only and then the program finishes (i.e. no deadlocks etc). The worker threads are terminated properly in the Drop trait implementation (this code is not shown). I'd appreciate any suggestions about debugging such a problem: putting a breakpoint ar recv() and trying to find something meaningful in its internals hasn't helped much.

```
type Job = Box<dyn FnOnce(usize) -> String + Send + 'static>;
enum Message {
    Run(Job),
    Halt,
}
struct Worker {
    id: usize,
    thread: Option<thread::JoinHandle<()>>,
}
pub struct ThreadPool {
    workers: Vec<Worker>,
    ingress_tx: Sender<Message>,
    pub egress_rx: Receiver<String>
}

impl Worker {
    fn new(id: usize, rx: Arc<Mutex<mpsc::Receiver<Message>>>, tx: mpsc::Sender<String>) -> Worker {
        let thread = thread::spawn(move ||
            loop {
                let msg = rx.lock().unwrap().recv().unwrap();
                match msg {
                    Message::Run(job) => {
                        let s = job(id);
                        println!("Sending \"{}\"", s);
                        tx.send(s).unwrap();
                    },
                    Message::Halt => break,
                }
            }
        );
        Worker {id, thread: Some(thread)}
    }
}
impl ThreadPool {
    pub fn new(size: usize) -> Result<ThreadPool, ThreadPoolError> {
        if size <= 0 {
            return Err(ThreadPoolError::ZeroSizedPool)
        }
        let (ingress_tx, ingress_rx) = mpsc::channel();
        let ingress_rx = Arc::new(Mutex::new(ingress_rx));
        
        let (egress_tx, egress_rx) = mpsc::channel();
    
        let mut workers = Vec::with_capacity(size);
        for id in 0..size {
            workers.push(Worker::new(id, ingress_rx.clone(), egress_tx.clone()));
        }
        
        Ok(ThreadPool {workers, ingress_tx, egress_rx})
    }
    pub fn execute<F>(&self, f: F)
        where F: FnOnce(usize) -> String + Send + 'static
    {
        let j = Box::new(f);
        self.ingress_tx.send(Message::Run(j)).unwrap();
    }
}

fn run_me(id: usize, i: usize) -> String {
    format!("Worker {} is processing tile {}...", id, i).to_string()
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod threadpool_tests {
    use super::*;
    #[test]
    fn tp_test() {
        let tpool = ThreadPool::new(4).expect("Cannot create threadpool");
        
        for i in 0..10 {
            let closure = move |worker_id| run_me(worker_id, i);
            tpool.execute(closure);
        }
        for s in tpool.egress_rx.recv() {
            println!("{}", s);
        }        
    }
}
```

And the output is:

```
Sending "Worker 0 is processing tile 0..."
Sending "Worker 0 is processing tile 2..."
Sending "Worker 3 is processing tile 1..."
Sending "Worker 3 is processing tile 4..."
Sending "Worker 2 is processing tile 3..."
Sending "Worker 2 is processing tile 6..."
Sending "Worker 1 is processing tile 5..."
Sending "Worker 0 is processing tile 7..."
Sending "Worker 0 is processing tile 9..."
Sending "Worker 3 is processing tile 8..."
Receiving "Worker 0 is processing tile 0..."
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, you have `for s in tpool.egress_rx.recv()`, which isn't doing quite what you want. Instead of iterating over the values received by the channel, you're receiving one element (wrapped in a `Result`) and then iterating over that, since `Result` implements `IntoIterator` to iterate over the success value (or nothing, if it contains an error).

Simply changing this to `for s in tpool.egress_rx` should fix it, since channels also implement `IntoIterator`.

Comment: Thanks so much! This has definitely unblocked me, so I've accepted the answer. The solution you proposed doesn't work because of the following error: "cannot move out of type `ThreadPool`, which implements the `Drop` trait". But I found the way to fix it (put the egress receiver inside an Option and then take it from the ThreadPool instance, and then iterate over it the way you suggested. Everything is working now!

Comment: @ValeriyKazantsev ah, in that case you should be able to simply use `for s in &tpool.egress_rx` instead, so that you create an iterator from a `&Receiver` (by reference) rather than the `Receiver` (by value, which requires moving). This way, you shouldn't need the `Option` at all. If it's easier to read, `for s in tpool.egress_rx.iter()` should also work.